# Read multiple Excel files with slight differences in sheet names

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I am trying to import multiple excel files with multiple sheets. The sheets reference the quarter and have Q1, Q2 , Q3 and Q4 in their names, which I want to be on separate data frames. However, some excel files have sheet names like QTR1 or Qtr1 instead. I want to know if there's a way I can read in sheets with the name Q1, QTR1 and Qtr1?
The following is the code I already have but it doesn't produce a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import re 

file_path = 'W/Energy-data/Prices/Company_Q1.xlsx'
file=pd.ExcelFile(file_path)

file.sheetnames

dataframes =[]
for sheet in file.sheet_names:
if re.match('Q1*', sheet) or re.match('Qtr 1*', sheet) or re.match('QTR 1*', sheet):
dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet))
```

Comment: Please don't use a screen shot: post the code, and format it as a code block in the question.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), How to Ask, and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When you say "it doesn't run", what actually happens when you run this?  Welcome to Stack Overflow!